# Assigning specific colors to columns in geom_col()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I produced a geom_col() that has 13 separate columns on it. I would like to assign a specific color to the columns: for example, I have "Teams" on the x axis, and "AVG Attendance" of the teams on the y axis.

Of the 13 teams, I would like my specific team's column to be colored red so it stands out, four of the other columns (teams newly added to league) to be in green, and the other 9 existing teams to be in blue.

I can only get ALL of the columns to be one color if I use - geom_col(fill = "blue").

How do I differentiate the columns to have a separate color grouped by the way I described above? I have spent many days googling this and I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  However, in short, you need to create a new column that defines the three "colour groups" you want.  Then use this new column (`colourCol`, say) in a `group=colourCol` parameter *inside* your `aes()` call.  This will override the default grouping created by the `fill=` parameter.  You can then control the colours and labels actually used in a `scale_fill_xxxx()` call.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I added the color grouping within the geom_col by going: (fill = color1) where color 1 is my new column with color grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Notes in the code...

```
# need dplyr and ggplot
library(tidyverse)

# make our random numbers the same
set.seed(123)

# fake minimum reproducible example
game_df <- tibble(team = LETTERS[1:13],
                  attendance = sample(5000:10000, 13),
                  # this is hand coded but you should find a way to do this automatically using existing data
                  # or use mutate() to create a new column with a calculation
                  color_group = c('old','old','new', 'new', 'old', 'highlight','old','new','old','new','old','old','old') )

# plot
game_df %>% 
  ggplot (., aes(x = team, y = attendance,  fill = color_group)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_color_manual( values = c('red','blue','green'))
```